# How to get winforms to open chrome to a specified URL when the user clicks a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make an application that allows me to input a URL into a textbox and make it open chrome with that URL.

so what I need is some way to make a variable work with the private void of the button. currently I cannot get the variable to work in the private void of the button, the button has the code to open chrome with the specified URL.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Zero_Light_Fullstack
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string link1 = textBox1.Text;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start("chrome", @link1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: See following : https://www.howtogeek.com/663927/how-to-open-google-chrome-using-command-prompt-on-windows-10/

Comment: You are attributing `textbox1`'s text to the `link1` variable right when the form starts, it is never changed afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `link1` inside of the scope of the method because you want to capture the text of the text box when the button is clicked, not when the form is instantiated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string link1 = textBox1.Text;
        Process.Start("chrome", link1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: if chrome is not found please try to add full path to chrome.exe like -> Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", urlToDownload);

Answer (score 2):

Do you **really** need Chrome to open? If not, you can simply do this:

```
Process.Start(textBox1.Text); // It is safer to directly use the Text property
```

This will open the link in the **default** browser. If you need Chrome:

```
try {
    Process.Start("chrome.exe", textBox1.Text); // It is safer to directly use the Text property
} catch {
    MessageBox.Show("Chrome is not installed probably");
}
```

Remember to put this in the `Click` event.